# Coin selection algorithm in Python to optimally select UTXO

Tags: bitcoin-core, python, coin-selection

Does anyone know of a good coin selection algorithm ***in Python*** that's perhaps similar to the one in Bitcoin Core (currently this: [github/bitcoin/src/wallet.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.5.3/src/wallet.cpp#L760) *(per guidance from [stackexchange/1077](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/what-is-the-coin-selection-algorithm))*)?

I see the popular python libraries: [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) and [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin) both seem to be selecting all existing UTXOs which might not be optimal, and might fail @over 100 utxos. Andreas Antonopoulos' ["greedy selection algo"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=k3qrBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT132&lpg=PT132&dq=greedy%20algorithm%20select%20utxo&source=bl&ots=7B3n_2Q33M&sig=7JHq6wDmcLGVPGbvcu7xnf4aTBg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi32Jubj5HOAhXsKsAKHbCdClYQ6AEIFDAA) is not as efficient as that in `wallet.cpp` of Bitcoin Core, am I right?

Comment: Just a note, there is no 'optimal' coin selection algorithm. There are trade-offs between privacy, UTXO set size, and a few other things, as is described well here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/32145/18196.

Comment: I'm currently compiling a master thesis on the topic of coin selection and I'm not aware of a Python implementation of Bitcoin Core's coin selection algorithm. I am however not up-to-date whether there are more Bitcoin wallet implementations in Python.

Comment: thanks so much @StephenM347 , Murch 's response: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/32445/15567 alludes to what I am after, but as he pointed out, there is no such implementation in Python yet. Since I am looking to replicate what Bitcoin Core does(admittedly not optimal), I will code it up in Python from guidance on that post and paste on here later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently compiling a master thesis on the topic of coin selection and I'm not aware of a Python implementation of Bitcoin Core's coin selection algorithm.

Comment: thanks @Murch ! Your response: bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/32445/15567 alludes to what I am after, but as you pointed out, there is no such implementation in Python yet. Since I am looking to replicate what Bitcoin Core does(admittedly not optimal), I will code it up in Python from guidance on that post and paste on here later.